# Mongo get 10 documents at a certain index in the collection

Tags: mongodb

How can I get 10 documents at a certain index of a collection in mongo?

```
var amount = 10;
db.myCollection.find(index, amount);
```

Comment: do you mean to get 10 documents for a certain filter?

Comment: Try `db.myCollection.find(index).limit(amount)`